# Concurrent transactions result in race condition with unique constraint on insert

Tags: postgresql, transaction, plpgsql, concurrency, upsert

I have a web service (http api) which allows a user to restfully create a resource. After authentication and validation I pass off the data to a Postgres function and allow it to check authorisation and create the records in the database.

I found a bug today when two http requests had been made within the same second which caused this function to be called with identical data twice. There is a clause inside the function which makes a select on a table to see if a value exists, if it does exist then I take the ID and use that on my next operation, if it doesn't then I insert the data, get back the ID and then use that on the next operation. Below is a simple example.

```
select id into articleId from articles where title = 'my new blog';
if articleId is null then
    insert into articles (title, content) values (_title, _content)
    returning id into articleId;
end if;
-- Continue, using articleId to represent the article for next operations...
```

As you can probably guess, I got a phantom read on the data where both transactions entered the `if articleId is null then` block and tried to insert onto the table. One succeeded and the other blew up because of a unique constraint on a field.

I've had a look around at how to defend against this and found a few different options but none seem like they fit our needs for a few reasons and I'm struggling to find any alternatives.

1. `insert ... on conflict do nothing/update...` I first looked at the `on conflict` option which looked good however the only option is to `do nothing` which then doesn't return the ID of the record that caused the collision, and `do update` won't work as it will cause triggers to be fired off when in reality the data hasn't changed. In some instances this isn't a problem but in many cases this might invalidate sessions user sessions which isn't something we can do.
2. `set transaction isolation level serializable;` this seems like the most attractive answer, however even our test suite can cause read/write dependencies where, like the above, we want to insert if something doesn't exist and return it if it does and carry on with further operations. If we have several transactions pending that run the above code it will cause a [read/write dependency error as outlined in the transaction-iso of the Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

**How should is this sort of concurrent read/write transaction handled?**

Neither myself or my team claim to be database experts, let alone Postgres experts but feel like this must be a solved problem, or one people have come across in the past. We're open to any suggestions. If the information provided above is not enough, please comment and I'll add more information as needed.

Comment: perhaps update only columns that have no update triggers watching them (and don't change the value in those columns),  or put `if new is not distinct from old then return new; end if;` at the top of all your update triggers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `insert` first, with `on conflict ... do nothing` and `returning id`.
If the value already exists, you will get no result from this statement, so you have then to execute a `select` to get the ID.

If two transactions try to do this at the same time, one of them will block on the `insert` (because the database does not yet know if the other transaction will commit or rollback), and continue only after the other transaction has finished.

Comment: Thanks for this, a simple solution but one we overlooked as it would potentially end up being done in many places. That said, it doesn't mean it's bad, just means we've got some work to do!

Comment: While this is simple and should work in most cases, it can still find no row  (though the row is there) or find a row in the `SELECT`, which a concurrent transaction already deleted (yet uncommitted). Under heavy concurrent load you might have to do more (loop), like the other answers illustrate.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I tested this. Please provide a sequence of commands that shows the problem.

Comment: I discussed possible issues in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter In my test, the sentence "The SELECT sees the same snapshot from the start of the query and also cannot return the yet invisible row." appears to be wrong. [In two connections: C1: BEGIN; C2: BEGIN; C1: INSERT; C2: tries same INSERT, blocks; C1: COMMIT; C2: unblocks; C2: SELECT sees the new row.] Again, please provide an example that proves the existence of the problem.

Comment: Note the difference between a nested `SELECT` in a CTE and a separate `SELECT` statement. Your separate `SELECT` operates on a new snapshot.  But there is a time frame between `INSERT` and `SELECT` that allows race conditions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter *This* question does not have any CTE. And please provide the sequence of commands what would lead to a race condition.

Comment: You have quoted a sentence from my related answer out of context, which applies applies to the CTE case. I have no time for a test case right now. If you won't believe me, feel free. I have provided plenty of information.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Reviewing your other post, what happens if we were to add a retry loop around `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING ... SELECT existingRow`? I assume this would protect one against inserts that are not visible yet. It would be less efficient than the single statement you proposed, but would it be safe?

Comment: @Gili: Isn't that what my answer here suggests? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213625/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry, you're right. I'll post a follow-up question there.

Answer (score 14):

The root of the problem is that, with default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, each concurrent UPSERT (or any query, for that matter) can only see rows that were visible at the start of the query. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED)

> When a transaction uses this isolation level, a `SELECT` query (without
> a `FOR UPDATE`/`SHARE` clause) sees only data committed before the query
> began; it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed
> during query execution by concurrent transactions.

But a `UNIQUE` index is *absolute* and still has to consider concurrently entered rows - even yet invisible rows. So you can get an exception for a unique violation, but you still cannot *see* the conflicting row *within the same query*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED)

> `INSERT` with an `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause may have insertion not
> proceed for a row due to the outcome of another transaction whose
> effects are not visible to the `INSERT` snapshot. Again, this is only
> the case in Read Committed mode.

The brute-force "solution" to this problem is to overwrite conflicting rows with `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`. The new row version is then visible within the same query. But there are several side effects and I would advice against it. One of them is that `UPDATE` triggers get fired - the thing you want to avoid expressly. Closely related answer on SO:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)

The remaining option is to start a new command (in the same transaction), which then can *see* these conflicting rows from the previous query. Both existing answers suggest as much. [The manual again:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED)

> However, `SELECT` does see the effects of previous updates executed
> within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed.
> Also note that two successive `SELECT` commands can see different data,
> even though they are within a single transaction, if other
> transactions commit changes after the first `SELECT` starts and before
> the second `SELECT` starts.

But **you want more**:

> -- Continue, using articleId to represent the article for next operations...

If concurrent write operations might be able to change or delete the row, to be absolutely sure, you also have to ***lock*** the *selected* row. (The *inserted* row is locked anyway.)

And since you seem to have very competitive transactions, to make sure you succeed, ***loop*** until success. Wrapped into a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_articleid(_title text, _content text, OUT _articleid int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT articleid
      FROM   articles
      WHERE  title = _title
      FOR    UPDATE          -- or maybe a weaker lock 
      INTO   _articleid;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;

      INSERT INTO articles AS a (title, content)
      VALUES (_title, _content)
      ON     CONFLICT (title) DO NOTHING  -- (new?) _content is discarded
      RETURNING a.articleid
      INTO   _articleid;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860)

Comment: What are the advantages of looping inside a stored function vs looping in the application layer? I know it saves us some network I/O, but are there any other advantages? I ask because I am trying to avoid stored procedures/functions if possible.

Comment: @Gili: Going back and forth between client and server for this can be a huge performance penalty, especially under concurrent write load - which this is all about. With multiple clients, you have to make sure that all implement it properly. Wrapped in a single function, there is a single source of truth that works the same for all and can be updated without touching (possibly many) SQL queries using it. Also, integrating the functionality in bigger queries can get complex quickly. Any particular reason to avoid server-side functions?

Comment: @Gili: But doing everything within the same transaction, you can loop in client code as well.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with stored procedures/functions. I just prefer to treat the database strictly as a data store, and the application strictly as a behavior store. There are tooling advantages to this (it's easier to debug), and business advantages (it's easier to hire).

My case is probably the exception to the rule. I do not have a heavy concurrent write load. I just want to ensure that the code is safe from concurrency bugs.

Comment: What a to the point answer!

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to just do the insert, and catch the error and handle it properly.  If you are prepared to handle errors, serializable isolation level is (apparently) unnecessary for your case.  If you are not prepared to handle errors, serializable isolation level won't help--it will just create even more errors you aren't prepared to handle.

Another option would be to do the ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING and then if nothing happens, follow up by doing the query you are already doing to get the must-be-there-now value.  In other words, move `select id into articleId from articles where title = 'my new blog';` from a pre-emptive step to a step only executed if ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING does in fact do nothing.  If it is possible for a record to be inserted and then deleted again, then you should do this in a retry loop.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to take a look at the on conflict do nothing initially and read around more on proper postgres error catching and see which ones make the code most readable. I imagine we'll use some combination of both throughout our code now.