# INSERT with ON CONFLICT does not insert rows as expected

Tags: postgresql, index, unique-constraint, bulk-insert, postgresql-12

We have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE listing_master (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    feed_id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    feed_listing_id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    updated_time timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX listing_master_pkey ON listing_master(id int4_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX listing_master_feed_id_feed_listing_id_idx ON listing_master(feed_id text_ops,feed_listing_id text_ops);
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE listing (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    mls_num character varying(20),
    feed_listing_id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    feed_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    list_price double precision,
    postal_code character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    photos_count integer,
    unparsed_address character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    city character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    status character varying(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new'::character varying,
    processing_status character varying(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none'::character varying,
    last_update_from_feed timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
    images_data jsonb,
    coordinates point,
    raw_data jsonb,
    deleted_date timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
    state_or_province text,
    country text,
    type character varying(40) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    ownership_type character varying(40) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    bedrooms integer,
    living_area integer,
    lot_size integer,
    year_built integer
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN listing.images_data IS '(DC2Type:json_array)';

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX listing_pkey ON listing(id int4_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX listing_feed_id_feed_listing_id_idx ON listing(feed_id text_ops,feed_listing_id text_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX listing_mls_num_feed_id_state_or_province_idx ON listing(mls_num text_ops,feed_id text_ops,state_or_province text_ops) WHERE state_or_province IS NOT NULL AND status::text = 'live'::text AND mls_num IS NOT NULL AND deleted_date IS NULL;
```

`listing_master` is populated from an API call and holds all the records that eventually have to exist in the `listing` table.

So, let's assume
`listing_master` has 100k records
`listing` has somewhat less

In order to verify that I ran this query:

```
select * 
from listing_master 
where feed_id = 'ddf' 
 and feed_listing_id not in (select feed_listing_id 
                             from listing 
                             where feed_id = 'ddf' 
                               and deleted_date is null );
```

And, as promised, this gave me 136 records back.

Now, I want to populate the missing listings from `listing_master` into `listing`, and trying it this way:

```
insert into listing(feed_id,feed_listing_id,status,processing_status) 
select lm.feed_id, lm.feed_listing_id, 'new' as status,'none' as processing_status 
from listing_master lm 
on conflict (feed_id,feed_listing_id) do nothing;
```

For some reason, this inserts 0 records, while it clearly should add 136 of them.
What am I missing?

I am in PostgreSQL 12.

Answer (score 2):

I see an elephant in the room:

```
... and deleted_date is null
```

There can be rows with non-null `deleted_date`, which are ignored by your test with  `SELECT` but still conflict in the unique index on `(feed_id,feed_listing_id)`.

Aside, `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` is almost always a bad choice. Even if it's not going to break completely with all `NOT NULL` columns in your case, it still typically delivers bad performance. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   listing_master  m
WHERE  feed_id = 'ddf' 
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM listing 
   WHERE  feed_id = 'ddf' 
   AND    feed_listing_id = m.feed_listing_id
   AND    deleted_date is null                 -- ?????
   );
```

What's more, even with `deleted_date is null` out of the way, this expectation of yours is strictly incorrect:

> ... while it clearly should add 136 of them.

You only tested for `feed_id = 'ddf'`. There can be any number of additional rows with a different `feed_id`. So it would be *"at least 136 of them"*.

---

If that's not it, we need to talk about possible concurrent write access. Related:

- [Concurrent transactions result in race condition with unique constraint on insert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212580/concurrent-transactions-result-in-race-condition-with-unique-constraint-on-inser/213625#213625)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)

Or possible index corruption. In this case the cure would be:

```
REINDEX INDEX listing_feed_id_feed_listing_id_idx;
```

Comment: For the last couple of days I am trying to make sense of your answer, and I am not sure I get it. Some things to clarify though: Currently, there is only one `feed_id` in the system. 
#2. Since the data is initially coming from an external feed, it is impossible to have duplicate `feed_listing_id` if it was already deleted.

Comment: If so, you can as well test with this simpler query:
`SELECT * FROM listing_master m WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM listing WHERE feed_listing_id = m.feed_listing_id)` Still missing rows? But are you sure your assumptions are true? Test, rather than just assume. Like Sherlock Holmes said: *"When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."*

Comment: Yeah, these are not assumptions, I tested and retested these things.